# Как создать vector объектов класса с динамическим выделением памяти в классе?

Tags: c++, ооп, указатели, память, vector

Необходимо считывать матрицы из файлов. Матрицы считываеются правильно, проблема в том, чтобы запихнуть обьекты класса в vector.
При отладке выдает "...нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу..." в файле delete_scalar.cpp. Еще заметил, что при считывании каждого нового файла для предыдущего элемента vector вызывается деструктор

```
//main.cpp
#include "SLAE.h"
const std::vector<std::string> fileNames = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
int main()
{
    std::vector<SLAE> tests;

    for (const auto& f : fileNames)
        tests.emplace_back(f);
}
```

```
//SLAE.h
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class SLAE
{
private:
    double** array;
    int arraySize;
public:
    SLAE();
    SLAE(const std::string&);
    ~SLAE();
};
```

```
//SLAE.cpp
#include "SLAE.h"
SLAE::SLAE(){}

SLAE::SLAE(const std::string& file)
{
    std::ifstream readStream(file);
    readStream >> arraySize;

    //Выделение памяти
    array = new double*[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        array[i] = new double[arraySize+1];

    //Чтение из файла
}
SLAE::~SLAE()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        delete[](array[i]);
    }
    delete[](array);
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас нет копирующего конструктора, поэтому при вставке в вектор выполняется генерируемое поверхностное копирование (копирование указателя, а не памяти), соответственно, получается повторное удаление (освобождение) уже освобожденной памяти, отсюда и проблемы.

Напишите корректный копирующий конструктор.

Да и в конструкторе по умолчанию хотя бы занулите указатель - с соответствующей проверкой в деструкторе (если нулевой указатель - то цикл удалений не выполнять).